# Spark 3.2.2 Joining same dataframe multiple time does not drop column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

We have some PySpark code that joins a table **table_a**, twice to another table **table_b** using the following code. After joining the table twice, we drop the **key_hash** column from the output DataFrame.

This code was working fine in spark version **3.0.1**. Since upgrading to spark version **3.2.2**, the behaviour has changed and during the first transform operation the **key_hash** field gets dropped from the output DataFrame but when the 2nd transform operation gets executed then the **key_hash** field still stays in the output_df.
Can someone please guide what has changed in Spark behaviour that is causing this issue?

```
def tr_join_sac_user(self, df_a):

def inner(df_b):
    return (
        df_b.join(df_a, on=df_b["sac_key_hash"] == df_a["key_hash"], how="left")
        .drop(df_a.key_hash)
        .drop(df_b.sac_key_hash)
    )

return inner

def tr_join_sec_user(self, df_a):

    def inner(df_b):
        return (
            df_b.join(df_a, on=df_b["sec_key_hash"] == df_a["key_hash"], how="left")
            .drop(df_a.key_hash)
            .drop(df_b.sec_key_hash)
        )

    return inner

table_a_df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/path/to/table_a")
table_b_df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/path/to/table_b")

output_df = table_b_df.transform(tr_join_sac_user(table_a_df))
output_df = output_df.transform(tr_join_sec_user(table_a_df))
```

If we use **.drop('key_hash')** instead of **.drop(df_a.key_hash)** that seems to work and the column does get dropped in 2nd transform as well. I would like to understand what has changed in Spark behaviour between these versions (or if it’s a bug) as this might have an impact in other places in our codebase as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also have an issue with this one, I don't know if its a bug or not but it seems not happening all time

```
utilization_raw = time_lab.crossJoin(approved_listing)
utilization_raw = utilization_raw\
.join(availability_series,
     ((utilization_raw.date_series == availability_series.availability_date)&\
      (utilization_raw.listing_id == availability_series.listing_id)),"left")\
.drop(availability_series.listing_id).dropDuplicates()\ --> WORKING
.join(request_series,
     ((utilization_raw.date_series==request_series.request_date_series)&\
      (utilization_raw.listing_id == request_series.listing_id)),"left")\
.drop(request_series.listing_id)\ --> WORKING
.join(listing_pricing,
     ((utilization_raw.date_series==listing_pricing.price_created_date)&\
     (utilization_raw.listing_id==listing_pricing.listing_id)),'left').drop(listing_pricing.listing_id)\ --> NOT WORKING
```

Here's the result of `printSchema()`

```
root
 |-- date_series: date (nullable = false)
 |-- week_series: date (nullable = true)
 |-- month_series: date (nullable = true)
 |-- woy_num: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- doy_num: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- dow_num: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- listing_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- is_driverless: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- listing_deleted_at: date (nullable = true)
 |-- daily_gmv: decimal(38,23) (nullable = true)
 |-- daily_nmv: decimal(38,23) (nullable = true)
 |-- daily_calendar_gmv: decimal(31,13) (nullable = true)
 |-- daily_calendar_nmv: decimal(31,13) (nullable = true)
 |-- active_booking: long (nullable = true)
 |-- is_available: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- is_requested: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- listing_id: integer (nullable = true) --> duplicated
 |-- base_price: decimal(10,2) (nullable = true)
```

Update: what we did is we updated the databricks version from 9.1 to 11.3